# D3 fill shape when draw with path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 to draw a certain shape layout for my map and the drew area has to be shaded.  I am using line path to achieved the shape, What I couldn't figured out is how do I shade (fill) the area with a certain color.  See picture for an example shape, just random in this case for visual aid. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to checkout the fill style property on paths.

```
<style>
path {  
 fill: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you, I'm not sure what I did before that didn't work.  Fill was the first i tried. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill the area described by these paths, simply assign the CSS attribute `fill`.